# Finding lengths in a diagram.

Tags: geometry

Find $x$ and $y$.

[image: The Problem]

Given that:
$$a_1+a_2+a_3-a_4+a_5=180^\circ$$

$$\text{cos}(180^\circ-a_5)=0.4$$

I managed to solved this problem using Mathematica based on an equation with whole bunch of ArcTan. However, I am looking for an easier way to solve it based on its geometrical properties.

Thank you!.

Remark:

- Thanks @Blue for editing the question!
- code for solving the problem in Mathematica:

`ratio = Tan[ArcCos[0.4]];
Solve[ArcTan[ratio*x/(10-x)]+ArcTan[ratio*x/(3-x)]+Pi-ArcTan[ratio*x/(x-1)]+Pi-ArcCos[0.4]-(Pi-ArcTan[ratio*x/(x-0.1)])==Pi&&x>1&&x<3,x]`

Comment: There seems to be lacking a question here.

Comment: There's no question here, and there's no question and the linked page (and please don't link pages here in any case)!

Comment: Updated the image, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: There are things strange is your expression : ArcTan[ratio*x/x]

Comment: I don't know if "geometrical properties" will help. Expanding $\tan(a_1+a_2+a_3-a_4+a_5)$ (which equals $0$), making substitutions the $\tan a_i$, and using the known relation between $y$ and $x$, I arrive at an irreducible quartic equation $$240 - 688 x + 21248 x^2 - 13864 x^3 - 1125 x^4 = 0$$ One of the real roots ($1.3561\ldots$) matches the result of your Mathematica code. (I'll note that we have both flipped signs on all the $x$-coordinates.) The exact expression for that root is quite ugly, dashing hopes of a nice solution. (FYI: The other real root of the polynomial is $-13.705\ldots$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x=t\cos a_5,\\y=t\sin a_5 $$ where $a_5$ is given by the second equation.

Then there remains a sum of four angles which can indeed be expressed as arc tangents of terms $t_k:=y/(x-x_k)$.

As

$$\tan(a_1+a_2+a_3-a_4)=\frac{\tan(a_1+a_2)+\tan(a_3-a_4)}{1-\tan(a_1+a_2)\tan(a_3-a_4)}
=\frac{\dfrac{t_1+t_2}{1-t_1t_2}+\dfrac{t_3-t_4}{1+t_3t_4}}{1-\dfrac{t_1+t_2}{1-t_1t_2}\dfrac{t_3-t_4}{1+t_3t_4}}$$ you will get a ratio of cubic/quartic polynomials in $t$.

I don't see a possible simplification among the terms so this problem seems to be equivalent to the resolution of a quartic equation. There will be no easy shortcut.